# add repeating number regex pattern in `.gitignore`

Tags: git

Python `logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler` generates log files like this:

- `file_name.log`
- `file_name.log.1`
- `file_name.log.2`
- `file_name.log.3`
- ...
- `file_name.log.100`

I was trying to add these in `.gitignore` by using this pattern `*.log.[0-9]+`, which doesn't seem to work. so any way to do that without using `*.log.*`, it should only ignore `.log.<number>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.gitignore` uses shell patterns, not regular expressions](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format). Shell patterns are noticeably more efficient in this use, but they're not as flexible.

To get what you want you'll have to use something like

```
filename.log
filename.log.[1-9]*
!filename.log.[1-9]*[^0-9]*
```

"ignore `filename.log` without an extension, or with a single-digit nonzero number extension, or with any extension that starts that way except don't ignore them if  they contain a nondigit anywhere".